# Convert Pandas Dataframe Row and Column to Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have created a matrix in dataframe to compare words and have converted it to numpy using "penaltymatrix = np.array(df.values)". How do I convert the rows and columns also?

[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwKMx.png)

The top part is the numpy array and the second part is the pandas dataframe which includes the appropiate column & row names.

Code:

```
def computeTable():
    sampInput = file1()
    refInput = file2()
    sampString = [word.strip(string.punctuation).lower() for word in sampInput.split()]
    refString = [word.strip(string.punctuation).lower() for word in refInput.split()]
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=sampString, columns=refString)


    penaltymatrix = np.array(df.values)
    penaltymatrix[0, 0] = 0
    print(penaltymatrix)
    print(3*"\n")
    print(df)
```

Comment: can you also tell us how your desired output should look? i mean if you want the headers of columns in dataframe as a list?

Comment: seems like you want index and columns also, use df.columns and df.index to get them

Comment: I need to write code to formulaically generate the table. I don't necessarily need the headers to show but I need to be able to manipulate specific elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```
def computeTable():
    sampInput = file1()
    refInput = file2()
    sampString = [word.strip(string.punctuation).lower() for word in sampInput.split()]
    refString = [word.strip(string.punctuation).lower() for word in refInput.split()]
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=sampString, columns=refString)

    penaltymatrix = np.hstack([np.array([0]+list(df.index)).reshape((-1, 1)), np.vstack([np.array(df.columns), df.values])])
    print(penaltymatrix)
    print(3*"\n")
    print(df)
```